# Show a div when Flexslider slide has class "flex-active-slide"

Tags: jquery, slideshow, show, flexslider

I am using Flexslider and everything is working fine. I have a div that will contain additional information within certain slides, but not necessarily all the slides. What I'm trying to accomplish is a jQuery animation for this div once the slide is displayed.

So, when the slide is active (it has class .flex-active-slide) the div would show, or slide down etc.

HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">

        <li id="test" >

            <div class="slide-content">
                <h1>Regular Content Here</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-excerpt group" style="display:none;">
                <p>Hidden Content...should show when active</p>
            </div>                          

        </li>

    </ul>
</div><!--end flexslider-->
```

JQUERY (this is what I've tried, but has no affect):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    if ($('li#test').hasClass('flex-active-slide')){
        $("div.slide-excerpt").show();
    };
});
```

Comment: I answered a similar question about flexslider recently. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18245511/490592

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally be more prone to handling this via the CSS.

```
.flexslider .slides .slide-excerpt {
    display:none;
}

.flexslider .slides .flex-active-slide .slide-excerpt {
    display:block;
}
```

and remove the inline style from your HTML (style="display:none").

Now, obviously, this only displays it. It doesn't add fancy animations. However, if you're already animating the slides into place, I'd hesitate before adding yet another animated element into the mix... too much of that makes for a very busy interface, and it can frustrate users having to wait too long to get to information that they might be interested in. If you must animate it, maybe you could still use CSS, but CSS3 animation, rather than javascript.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The reason I want/need animation is because the "excerpt" area falls below the slides adding another 200px in height. So, the transition between slides that are using the excerpt and slides that are not is "abrupt" without an animation...the content below the slide "jumps" up and down rather than doing so smoothly. Make sense?

Comment: Also, the inline "display:none;" is only inline in the example above, for simplicity's sake. In my dev site it's in my external stylesheet.

Comment: Hm. Sorry, I can't visualize it, there's not enough code to get a better idea of why this is not working for you. You could always relatively position the excerpt area within the slides that have them, so that they are always in the same location relative to where the slide is, which should keep the slide-height from changing, if that's what is going on, but that's really just a blind guess at this point, sorry.