# Use jquery to target classes that are added dynamically?

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have a slider (flexslider) that dynamically adds the class "flex-active-slide" to the active `<li>`.

I want to use jQuery to do something when a specific slide has the class "flex-active-slide." I tried the following, but it doesn't work because the .flex-active-class is added on the fly after this has already run:

```
if ( $('#slider li.about').is('.flex-active-slide')  ){  
   $('.nav li.about').show();
}
```

In my research, it seems I want to use on(), but all the examples I see relate it to an event like click() or hover(). This isn't triggered by anything like that -- the class just "appears." I can't figure out how to format it. Something like this...?

```
$(document).on('???',".flex-active-slide",  function() {
    $(".nav li.about").show();;
    })
```

I'm sure that is embarrassingly incorrect... I appreciate any help you can give!!

Note: I can't simply use CSS because the .nav I'm trying to affect is completely unrelated to the slider div.

UPDATE: Here is what appears to be the code in the flexslider.js that controls adding the flex-active-slide class. Is there anything here that suggests anything I could do?

```
 slider.flexAnimate = function(target, pause, override, withSync, fromNav) {

      if (asNav && slider.pagingCount === 1) slider.direction = (slider.currentItem < target) ? "next" : "prev";

      if (!slider.animating && (slider.canAdvance(target, fromNav) || override) && slider.is(":visible")) {
        if (asNav && withSync) {
          var master = $(vars.asNavFor).data('flexslider');
          slider.atEnd = target === 0 || target === slider.count - 1;
          master.flexAnimate(target, true, false, true, fromNav);
          slider.direction = (slider.currentItem < target) ? "next" : "prev";
          master.direction = slider.direction;

          if (Math.ceil((target + 1)/slider.visible) - 1 !== slider.currentSlide && target !== 0) {
            slider.currentItem = target;
            slider.slides.removeClass(namespace + "active-slide").eq(target).addClass(namespace + "active-slide");
            target = Math.floor(target/slider.visible);

          } else {
            slider.currentItem = target;
            slider.slides.removeClass(namespace + "active-slide").eq(target).addClass(namespace + "active-slide");
            return false;
          }
        }
...
```

Comment: You want something to happen automatically at the time the class is added? AFAIK, there's no way to do that. Check the documentation for flexslider to see if it offers its own handlers that you can bind to certain actions.

Comment: I've updated to include what appears to be the relevant section of the flexslider code... is there anything here that I can bind to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute force way is to poll it.

```
var poll = function(){
  if ( $('#slider li.about').is('.flex-active-slide')  ){  
    $('.nav li.about').show();
  } else {
    setTimeout(poll,500); // Sets how often to check in milliseconds
  }
}
```

That code will keep checking for the element every half a second, and then stop checking once it sees the element for the first time. If you want to keep checking for the element whenever the page is open, take the setTimeout out of the else.

The smarter way to do it is with a callback. Flexslider has a few different callbacks. I'm using the after callback here, this will execute after each slide animates on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    after: function(slider) {
      if($('#slider li.about').is('.flex-active-slide')) {
        $('.nav li.about').show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You have to call this on the correct element. I'm using `.flexslider`, but you will need to specify an identifier for your flexslider instance.

You can replace `if($('#slider li.about').is('.flex-active-slide'))` with something like `if(slider.currentSlide == 3)` to trigger your show() event after the third slide. Flexslider has more details about this in the advanced section on their home page. http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: YES!! The callback is what did it! I actually had to change it to start: instead of after: but that did the trick. THANK YOU.

Comment: @Lindsay Great! Any decent plugin is going to offer callbacks. Anytime they're available, they're usually the right way to trigger actions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MutationObservers to detect changes to the DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver. They're not as straightforward as, say, jQuery, but immensely useful.

Comment: I will have to look into this. I've never tried it. Though does this mean it's only going to work on Firefox?

Comment: I realize you've found a solution, but in the sake of providing a complete answer: Browser Support for MutationObserver can be found at http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `hasClass` method instead of `is`.

**example:**

```
if ( $('#slider li.about').hasClass('flex-active-slide')  ){  
   $('.nav li.about').show();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but sadly didn't affect anything. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Lindsay, this answer is only a different way of writing what you already had. It's not a solution to your problem, but I would indeed rather use `.hasClass` than  `.is`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind messing with the jQuery, you could use the [jquery.hook plugin](https://github.com/aheckmann/jquery.hook) and perhaps try the following:

```
$.hook('addClass');
$('#slider').delegate('onaddClass', function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('flex-active-slide') )
    {
        $(".nav li.about").show();
    }
});
```

For full disclosure though, I haven't tried this and I'm not sure if it'll impact the performance of your page :/ Let me know if you try this and how it goes..

Comment: This looked so promising, but no dice. I added the script, and copied the hook as you have it above. I tried switching 'delegate' to 'on' and also tried is instead of hasClass. Nothing seemed to make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Editing the flexslider script would be the simplest solution imho (because I haven't used Flexslider myself). Find the line where the flex-active-slide` class is toggled (which is probably also an if else clause), and input your function directly there.

If you don't want to edit the file, there is another, more 'performance-heavy' way using the good ol' `setInterval` function. You'd have something like:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if ( $('#slider li.about').hasClass('.flex-active-slide')  ){  
     $('.nav li.about').show();
  };
},200);
```

This will fire a function every 200 milliseconds checking if your li.about has the class.

There is also a new way of doing this, called webworkers, basically scripts that work in the background and eliminate the need to use a sluggish `setInterval()`. I haven't investigated it yet, but it seems pretty interesting: The [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) gives a good deal of info about it.